# How to distribute data from MongoDb to processors

Tags: mongodb, space

**Please help me also with adding PROPER TAGS**

I have a script that streams documents from mongo. It processes them one by one.

Here comes the problem. Processing a document takes some while. If running on 1 processor it's fine. But from 2+ processors, they can be reprocessing the same data. The processors will be added/removed dynamically depending on how our CI is busy.

How can I distribute the docs between the processors?

My ideas:

1. Distribution based on last digits of `doc._id`.
2. Whenever a processor is connected it writes a log to db. From the log other processors would calculate the ranges they should process. The problem is that the script is batch, say 500 docs per call.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You mean [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)?

Comment: @joao thx for trying but I don't mean sharding. I need to divide the space.